# The type of element "p: dataTable" must be followed by one of these attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

well, simply...the trouble is while i try to run my jsf proyect using primefaces, it does not..and splash on the browser an error screen what says

"Estado HTTP 500 - Error Parsing /Lista.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 37] El tipo de elemento "p:dataTable" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>"."

"HTTP Status 500 - /Lista.xhtml Parsing Error: Error Traced [line 37] The type of element "p: dataTable" must be followed by one of these attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

well i tried anything even clean and validating  and looking minutely each codeline, so..please help ill be glad of your help...

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="Template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<h:head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>

<p:panelGrid style="margin: 0 auto" columns="2">
<p:outputLabel value="Nombres" />
<p:inputText p:placeholder="Ej; Edward" value="#{personaBean.persona.nombre}"></p:inputText>
<p:outputLabel value="Apellidos" />
<p:inputText p:placeholder="Ej; Snowden"
value="#{personaBean.persona.apellido}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Sexo" style="center" />
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{personaBean.persona.sexo}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="Masculino." itemLabel="Masculino." />
<f:selectItem itemValue="Femenino." itemLabel="Femenino." />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton value="Enviar" actionListener="#{personaBean.agregamePersona}" update="dt" ></p:commandButton>
</p:panelGrid>
<!-- <p:growl id="msj" showDetail="true"/> -->

<p:dataTable id="dt" 
value="#{personaBean.lstPersonas}" 
border="1"var="p" rows="4" 
paginator="true"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
       {FirstPageLink}
       {PreviousPageLink}
       {PageLinks}
       {NextPageLink}
       {LastPageLink}
       {Exporters}" 
tableStyle="widh:auto" 
rowsPerPageTemplate="1,2,3,5" >

<p:column filterBy="#{p.nombre}" filterMatchMode="contains"headerText="Nombre" style="width:100px" >
<h:outputText value="#{p.nombre}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Apellido" filterBy="#{p.apellido}" filterMatchMode="contains"style="width:100px">
<h:outputText value="#{p.apellido}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Sexo" filterBy="#{p.sexo}" filterMatchMode="contains"style="width:100px" sortBy="#{p.sexo}">
<h:outputText value="#{p.sexo}" />
</p:column>

<p:column style="width:40px">
<h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="Actions" cellpadding="2">
<p:commandButton id="eraseButton" value="Eliminar"actionListener="#{personaBean.eliminamePersona(p)}" update="dt"  />

<p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:display" oncomplete="interactiveDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}" target="#{personaBean.persona}" />
</p:commandButton>

</h:panelGrid>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Detalle del cliente" widgetVar="interactiveDialog" resizable="false" id="dialogointeractivo"
          showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

<h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">

<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Datos de la fila seleccionada"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
<h:outputText value="#{personaBean.persona.nombre}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

<h:outputText value="Apellido"/>
<h:outputText value="#{personaBean.persona.apellido}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

<h:outputText value="Sexo"/>
<h:outputText value="#{personaBean.persona.sexo}" style="font-weight:bold"/>


</h:panelGrid>


</p:dialog> 

</h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put a space between the attributes "border" and "var" here : `border="1"var="p"`.

Comment: That's fine @Omar. The quotes should be enough to demarcate the attributes. OP should just run an XML validator on the document. Depending on your IDE, you should be able to just right click on the document and select "validate" or something similar

Comment: finally i solved it just..commenting , for example. <:p column></p:column> and re-writting all the tags one by one, and yep kolossus, i tried the validation and the project cleaning of eclipse E E, but it doesnt worked. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late for an answer however I experienced the same issue and it turns out that the problem is spaces in between the attributes for the `commandButton` tag as [@Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2459449/omar) pointed out.

The below gave me an error because of the none-existing space between `value` and `actionListener`  attributes.

```
<p:commandButton id="eraseButton" value="Eliminar"actionListener="#{personaBean.updateVal(p)}" />
```

However, after making space in between the attributes as illustrated below I never got the error again.

```
<p:commandButton id="eraseButton" value="Eliminar" actionListener="#{personaBean.updateVal(p)}" />
```